# How does one comply with the mypy type 'SupportsWrite[str]'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a 'smart' open function that opens a variety of files and returns an IO-ish object type:

```
def sopen(anything_at_all: str, mode: str) -> FileIO:
   ...
```

And I use it in a print statement like:

```
with sopen('footxt.gz', mode = 'w+') as fout:
    print("hello, world!", file=fout)
```

---

Then, when analyzing this code with `mypy` 0.812, I get the following mystery error:

```
Argument "fout" to "print" has incompatible type "FileIO"; expected "Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]"
```

Ok great: `SupportsWrite` is definitely better than `FileIO`, only one problem: when I adapt my code to support write using `_typeshed.SupportsWrite`, nothing gets better...

```
def sopen(anything_at_all: str, mode: str) \
  -> Union[SupportsWrite[str],SupportsRead[str]]:
  ...
```

`mypy` wants **exactly** `Optional[SupportsWrite]`:

```
 Argument "fout" to "print" has incompatible type "Union[SupportsWrite[str], SupportsRead[str]]"; expected "Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]"
```

---

Next I try casting, and creating some sort of type-casting enforcement, but in the middle of trying out my caster in the interpreter to see what errors fall out when:

```
>>> from _typeshed import SupportsRead, SupportsWrite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_typeshed'
```

And now the fundamental problem is: how does one comply, in this situation, with `mypy`'s wishes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Use `typing.IO` instead of `FileIO`. `typing.IO` supports all the return types that the built-in `open` might return.

---

`print` itself annotates its `file` argument as `Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]`, so `mypy` is correct.

To fix the missing `_typeshed` module error (also correct, it is only available when type checking, not when the interpreter is executing code) you can use the `if TYPE_CHECKING`<sup>1</sup> trick and then use string annotations.

The below **almost** satisfies `mypy`:

```
from typing import Optional, TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from _typeshed import SupportsWrite

def sopen(anything_at_all: str, mode: str) -> 'Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]':
   ...

with sopen('footxt.gz', mode = 'w+') as fout:
    print("hello, world!", file=fout)
```

Feeding this to `mypy` results with

```
test.py:9: error: Item "SupportsWrite[str]" of "Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]" has no attribute "__enter__"
test.py:9: error: Item "None" of "Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]" has no attribute "__enter__"
test.py:9: error: Item "SupportsWrite[str]" of "Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]" has no attribute "__exit__"
test.py:9: error: Item "None" of "Optional[SupportsWrite[str]]" has no attribute "__exit__"
```

Enters `typing.IO`.

Instead of messing with `SupportsWrite` directly, you can simply use `typing.IO` (which also happens to match `open`'s return types). The following fully satisfies `mypy`:

```
from typing import IO

def sopen(anything_at_all: str, mode: str) -> IO:
   ...

with sopen('footxt.gz', mode = 'w+') as fout:
    print("hello, world!", file=fout)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> `TYPE_CHECKING` is a constant which is `False` by default, and is only being set to `True` by `mypy` and/or other type analyzing tools.

Comment: if `sopen` does too much, then `open` does too much... no?  If I can't do as much as `open`, then `python3` is sort of a pair of water-wings, training wheels, bowling bumpers etc.  It says: leave the non-combinatorial work to us, and you can write all the combinatorial versions of the same function.  Cheers!

Comment: @Chris I've updated my answer with a solid fix. TLDR you should use `typing.IO`, not `FileIO` directly. I left all the other explanation for future reference