# How do I import the type hint SupportsWrite in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm working on a Python module, and I have a problem with a class. This class has a method called print, which prints the "self.data", instead of the string(s) provided.

Now, I want this module to be as useful as possible, for myself and maybe other people, and I want to preserve the parameters and type hints of the original print because it's the function used to make that method, and that gives extra utility without making my code any more complex, so, why not?.

My code:

```
from collections import UserString
from typing import Literal
from _typeshed import SupportsWrite

class Strool(UserString):
    def __init__(self, string) -> None:
        super().__init__(string)
    def print(self, end: str | None = "\n", file: SupportsWrite[str] | None = None, flush: Literal[False] = False):
        # ^^ Hints needed ^^
        print(self.data, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

While I'm writing code, the editor's checker doesn't raise any problem, but when I run the script this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\carlo\Desktop\CODE\CharliePad\strool.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _typeshed import SupportsWrite
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_typeshed'
```

From what I've heard, _typeshed is not available at runtime, that's why from the Python Interpreter's perspective, there's no module named "_typeshed", but I can't find any solution besides this.

What am I missing here? How do I correctly import the type hint?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69307511/how-does-one-comply-with-the-mypy-type-supportswritestr) suggests using `typing.IO` instead of `SupportsWrite[str]`.

Comment: `py -m pip install typeshed-client` Released: Feb 25, 2024

Comment: @toyotaSupra Can you elaborate on how that works?

Comment: Did u install it?

Comment: `_typeshed` does not exist at runtime, and you shouldn't ever import it without [putting it under `if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:`](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec/directives.html#type-checking).

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yes, I had it installed before, but I don't know how it works

Comment: @dROOOze , I tried that before, but I got NameError instead, because "SupportsWrite" doesn't exist. That probably shouldn't be a problem (I don't think type hints do anything during the execution of scripts), but it is because it breaks my program.

Comment: You need to either put the type in string quotes like the example in the link, or add `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of the file.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice that seems to work, at least it doesn't raise any errors while I'm not using it, and that's progress! I'll do more testing when I can :D